# rails rss namespace tag generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, rss

```
<title>Webisode 200 Playlist</title>

<item>

  <title>Testing 201</title>

  <media:credit role="author">Adam Houston</media:credit>

  <media:content url="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gb0bGZ06vXn" type="video/x-flv" />

  <jwplayer:duration>200</jwplayer:duration>

</item>
```

i'm using rails xml to generate the corresponding xml but my question is how do i generate tags with namespace like  or  also how do i tell xml about the attirbutes like role="author".

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `tag!` method if you want to create such tags:

```
xml.tag!("SOAP:Envelope") # => <SOAP:Envelope/>
```

attributes are passed as hash options:

```
xml.target("name"=>"compile") # => <target name="compile"\>
```

see the documentation for more infos:  http://ap.rubyonrails.org/classes/Builder/XmlMarkup.html#M000157

Comment: How do we get namespace as well as cdata tags together for an xml node?